# Unable to addEventListener() when trying to integrate external javascript code in rasa-webchat

Tags: javascript, rasa

I have created a Chatbot using Rasa and using rasa-webchat for UI. I am trying to block the user from using any profanity. I am able to achieve this by writing a JS code targeting the input field.

```
    function blockProfanity(){
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value);
    if (document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value.includes('fuck') || document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value.includes('Please refrain from using Profanity')){
        document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value = 'Please refrain from using Profanity';
        document.getElementsByName('message')[0].style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementsByName('message')[0].style.fontWeight = 900;
    } else{
        document.getElementsByName('message')[0].style.color = 'black';
        document.getElementsByName('message')[0].style.fontWeight = 200;
    }
}
alert("document loaded!");
document.getElementsByName('message')[0].addEventListener('keyup', blockProfanity);
```

This works fine on running from Chrome/Edge console, but when I am trying to add this script into the html code for rasa-webchat, I am getting the below error, no matter where I put it in the body tag:

```
index.html:64 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')
at index.html:64
```

below is the html code for integrating rasa-webchat

```
<html>
<body>
    <style>
      //custom styling
    </style>
    <script>!(function () {
    

    let e = document.createElement("script"),
            t = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            (e.src =
            "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat@1.0.1/lib/index.js"),
            // Replace 1.x.x with the version that you want
            (e.async = !0),
            (e.onload = () => {
                window.WebChat.default(
                {
                    initPayload: '/greet', 
                    customData: { language: "en" },
                    socketUrl: "http://localhost:5005",
                    title: 'X',
                    subtitle: 'Say hi to get started',
                    profileAvatar: './images/logo_white.jpg',
                    showFullScreenButton: true,
                    params: {storage: "session",},
                    displayUnreadCount: true,
                    showMessageDate: true,
                },
                null
                );
            }),
            t.insertBefore(e, t.firstChild);
        })();
        console.log('Done');
        function blockProfanity(){
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value);
    if (document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value.includes('fuck') || document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value.includes('Please refrain from using Profanity')){
        document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value = 'Please refrain from using Profanity';
        document.getElementsByName('message')[0].style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementsByName('message')[0].style.fontWeight = 900;
    } else{
        document.getElementsByName('message')[0].style.color = 'black';
        document.getElementsByName('message')[0].style.fontWeight = 200;
    }
}
alert("document loaded!");
document.getElementsByName('message')[0].addEventListener('keyup', blockProfanity);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot access the things rasa-webchat would create before it is loaded! Did you try adding your code in the onload callback, after you call window.WebChat.default?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there are no elements named `message` and hence `document.getElementsByName('message')[0]` is `undefined`.

I double-checked that [the minimalistic script for importing Rasa Webchat](https://github.com/botfront/rasa-webchat#in-a-script-tag) doesn't itself create an element named `message`. And neither do the added bits of code that led to the slightly bigger example in the OP. Maybe the bits of code referring to `message` are taken from some larger example where that element was created as well. If so, seeing that larger example would be helpful.